# NHibernate : Mapping a collection with single source in multiple subclasses

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have an abstract class that is stored with table-per-hierarchy strategy. Two of the subclasses have a few additional fields, one of whom is a collection from a different table. When trying to map this collection in .hbm file, NHibernate displays an error `The column 'QuestionId' has already been added in this SQL builder.`

If I leave only one of the subclasses, mapping seems to working fine (for the subclass that is left in the mapping, of course). From what I understand, NH is treating this situation as mapping duplicate, but it is meant to mapped once per subclass. Is there something I am missing for the mapping to work?

Mapping of the class in question:

```
  <class name="Question" table="Questions" lazy="false">
    <id name="Id" type="Int64" column="Id">
      <generator class="seqhilo">
        <param name="sequence">CommonId</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <discriminator column="QuestionType" type="String" insert="false"/>


    <natural-id>
      <component name="QuestionId" class="QuestionId">
        <property name="Id" column="QuestionId" not-null="true" />
      </component>
    </natural-id>

    ....

    <subclass name="SingleAnswerQuestion" discriminator-value="qtid_SingleAnswer">
      <set name = "AnswerOptions" table = "QuestionAnswerOptions" cascade="all-delete-orphan"  lazy="false">
        <key column = "QuestionId"  not-null="true" foreign-key="IX-QuestionId"/>
        <one-to-many class = "Questions.QuestionAnswerOption"/>
      </set>
        ...
    </subclass>

    <subclass name="MultiAnswerOptionQuestion" discriminator-value="qtid_MultiAnswer">
      <set name = "AnswerOptions" table = "QuestionAnswerOptions" cascade="all-delete-orphan"  lazy="false">
        <key column = "QuestionId"  not-null="true" foreign-key="IX-QuestionId"/>
        <one-to-many class = "QuestionAnswerOption" />
      </set>
        ...
    </subclass>
  </class>
```

Mapping for the collection element:

```
<class name="QuestionAnswerOption" table="QuestionAnswerOptions" lazy="false">
    <id name="Id" type="Int64" column="Id">
      <generator class="seqhilo">
        <param name="sequence">CommonId</param>
      </generator>
    </id>


    <property name="AttachmentId" column="AttachmentId" not-null="false"/>
    <property name="ThumbnailAttachmentId" column="ThumbnailAttachmentId" not-null="false"/>
    <property name="Description" column="Description" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="OrderNumber" column="OrderNumber" not-null="true"/>

</class>
```

Comment: can you post the query or code which throws the error?

Comment: Similarly to errors thrown in cases like missing properties in classes, its thrown when the site is initialized. No specific code call has been made yet.

Comment: I created a test implementation with the info specified. I don't get this error. i suspect QuestionId is mapped multiple times. Also any reason why you are not using mapping by code with fluentnhibernate or loquacious api?

Comment: Could you show me your mapping files? I will comb through my mappings again, but If it was mapped somewhere else, wouldnt having 1 of  the sets already show the issue?

Answer (score 0):

this works

**mappings**

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="NHibernateTest.Question">
    <id name="Id">
      <column name="Id" />
      <generator class="seqhilo">
        <param name="sequence">CommonId</param>
        <param name="max_lo">20</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <discriminator type="String">
      <column name="QuestionType" />
    </discriminator>
    <natural-id>
      <property name="QuestionId">
        <column name="QuestionId" />
      </property>
    </natural-id>
    <subclass name="NHibernateTest.SingleAnswerQuestion" discriminator-value="qtid_SingleAnswer">
      <set lazy="false" name="AnswerOptions">
        <key>
          <column name="QuestionId" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="NHibernateTest.AnswerOption" />
      </set>
    </subclass>
    <subclass name="NHibernateTest.MultiAnswerOptionQuestion" discriminator-value="qtid_MultiAnswer">
      <set name="AnswerOptions">
        <key>
          <column name="QuestionId" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="NHibernateTest.AnswerOption" />
      </set>
    </subclass>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="NHibernateTest.AnswerOption">
    <id name="Id">
      <column name="Id" />
      <generator class="seqhilo">
        <param name="sequence">CommonId</param>
        <param name="max_lo">20</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**mappings generated with**

```
class QuestionMap : ClassMap<Question>
{
    public QuestionMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.SeqHiLo("CommonId", "20");
        NaturalId().Property(x => x.QuestionId);

        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("QuestionType");
    }
}
class SingleAnswerQuestionMap : SubclassMap<SingleAnswerQuestion>
{
    public SingleAnswerQuestionMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("qtid_SingleAnswer");

        HasMany(x => x.AnswerOptions).AsSet().KeyColumn("QuestionId");
    }
}
class MultiAnswerOptionQuestionMap : SubclassMap<MultiAnswerOptionQuestion>
{
    public MultiAnswerOptionQuestionMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("qtid_MultiAnswer");

        HasMany(x => x.AnswerOptions).AsSet().KeyColumn("QuestionId");
    }
}
class AnswerOptionMap : ClassMap<AnswerOption>
{
    public AnswerOptionMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.SeqHiLo("CommonId", "20");
    }
}
```

**code**

```
class Question : Entity
{
    public virtual int QuestionId { get; set; }
}

class SingleAnswerQuestion : Question
{
    public virtual ICollection<AnswerOption> AnswerOptions { get; protected set; }
}
class MultiAnswerOptionQuestion : Question
{
    public virtual ICollection<AnswerOption> AnswerOptions { get; protected set; }
}

class AnswerOption : Entity { }

// run
session.Save(new SingleAnswerQuestion { QuestionId = 1 });
session.Save(new MultiAnswerOptionQuestion { QuestionId = 2 });
session.Flush();
session.Clear();

// 
var questions = session.Query<Question>().ToList();
```

I can reproduce it with Not.KeyNullable() because NHibernate tries to create 2 hidden backreferences `AnswerOptionsBackref` with the same column which i'm not sure what it is used for.

Comment: Biggest difference probably is the different column_name values in each of your sets. How are the AnswerOptions supposed to be stored in this case?  Does it have two different properties? I added the current mapping for QuestionAnswerOptions if that changes anything.

Comment: My bad, forgot that one. I changed them to be the same but still works

Comment: Thank you very much! Going backwards from your mapping to mine, I managed to make it work and isolate the specific part that caused the issue. Turns out the culprit was **not-null="true"**, which surprised me a lot.  Does it work the same way in your example?  We have a multiple cases where the structure of mapping is the same as was used here with exception of the subclass. Do you have any idea why that would be thing? If you do, please add that to your answer and I will mark that as the solution. Regardless, thank you very much!